# Issue getting version of usb Device in Android

Tags: android, usb

I trying to create an app that can detect a usb devices. The android device act like a Host, and I now only need to read data of attached devices.

I import *android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice*

All work fine, but the problem is with any [usbDevice](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice.html) methods. I can read the usbDevice.getDeviceName() method but I can't use for example getVersion(), whY?

He say me that cannos resolve this method. Also about other methods.

```
    private String readDevice(UsbDevice device) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String a =  device.getDeviceName(); //work
        String b = device.getVersion(); //doesn't work

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You need to read [This Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice.html#getVersion())
>
> It's included in API 23.

```
String versionStr = UsbDevice.getVersion();
```

> Or you may help from [This Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html)